# Visualforce email template table row conditional with no controller

Tags: apex, visualforce, email-template

I'm not very salesforce savvy and I need some assistance.

I need to separate the table below in two displays on the email

one for when the Type__c is Online and other when the Type__c is Inperson

I am having trouble making it work, then I tried like the code below it show me an Boolean expected error

for example is display it like this now and I want to separate by type and show two tables on for online and on for in person(where i have multiple results)
[image: ![enter image description here]

```
<apex:repeat var="rx" value="{!relatedTo.SDI_Rep_Trainings_Relationship__r}">
   <tr>
      <td>
         <apex:outputText value="{!IF(!rx.Type__c == 'Online', !rx.Type__c, '')}" />
      </td>
  </tr>
 </apex:repeat>
```

Edit1:
Managed to fix with @cropredy tips.

but now im am getting a new error when the field is outputField see code below complains about  "syntax error )". Any insight

````
<p>Online</p>

<table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="text-align: left;">

    <tr>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Start Time</th>
        <th>End Time</th>
        <th>Location</th>
    </tr>

    <apex:repeat var="rx" value="{!relatedTo.SDI_Rep_Trainings_Relationship__r}">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <apex:outputText value="{!IF(rx.Type__c == 'Online', rx.Type__c, '')}" />
            </td>



            <td>
                <apex:outputText value="{0,date,MM/dd/yy}">

                    <apex:param value="{!IF(rx.Type__c == 'Online', rx.Date__c, '')}" />

                </apex:outputtext>
            </td>



            <td>
                <apex:outputField value="{!IF(rx.Type__c == 'Online', rx.Training_Start_Time__c, '')}" />
            </td>



            <td>
                <apex:outputField value="{!IF(rx.Type__c == 'Online', rx.Training_End_Time__c, '')}" />
            </td>



            <td>
                <apex:outputText value="{{!IF(rx.Type__c == 'Online', rx.Location__c, '')}}" />
            </td>



        </tr>

    </apex:repeat>

</table> ```
````

Comment: Once you start a merge expression with `{!` - don't use any additional `{!` or `!` within the enclosing `{! ... }` - your `!rx.Type__c` means `NOT(Rx_Type__c)`

Comment: Thanks it fixed and seems to work, but got some other error when the field is outputField, updated the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have:

```
<apex:outputField value="{!IF(rx.Type__c == 'Online', rx.Training_Start_Time__c, '')}"
```

You can't do this -- `apex:outputFields` can't be dynamically specified in an IF block

Normally, you would use `rendered=` like this:

```
<apex:outputField value="{!rx.Training_Start_Time__c}"
    rendered="{!rx_Type__c = 'Online'}"/>
<apex:outputText value="" rendered={!NOT(rx_Type__c = 'Online')}"/>
```

I suspect you are trying to format a datetime value and that is why you are using `outputField`.

Note, normally, [outputField displays a label + value](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.238.0.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_outputField.htm?q=apex:outputField)

- This [SFDC Forum post](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000096kHIAQ) asserts that when `outputField` is used outside of a `pageBlockSection`, the label will not display.
- Alternatively, add the attribute `label=""` to the `outputField` to suppress

Comment: Thanks, rendered helped a lot  I used that with a combination of output panel to conditionally display using the rendered option.